# TFS Build Server for WP8 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to **install the Windows Phone 8 SDK on Windows Server 2008 R2** so it can be used as a build server?

It was possible for the Windows Phone 7 SDK, but the newer SDK has more stringent requirements (most due to the emulator which is not needed for a build machine, and Windows 8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 has a dependency on Windows 8 due to the use of WinRT APIs. Therefore Windows Server 2008 R2 is unlikely to work, but Windows Server 2012 should be fine as it shares the same kernel as Windows 8

Comment: I was afraid that was going to be the answer. Thanks for confirming though.